To define the number of bits associated with an instruction?
How do you find the number of bits associated with an instruction if the opcode is 1 byte for register to register mode using AX with register mode AX=000 CX=001 DX=010 BX=011
Tried solving it using the instruction format of 8086 couldnt get anywhere

Look at disassembly (or an assembler listing like from nasm -l /dev/stdout  foo.asm) that includes hex machine code as well as instructions.  The shortest instructions are 1 byte, like xchg ax, cx where AX is implicit, the other register is the low 3 bits of the instruction.  Many 2-register instructions are 2 bytes, opcode + ModRM.

Not totally clear what you're asking, like if there's a specific question different from How to tell the length of an x86 instruction? so I marked it as a duplicate.  If that doesn't answer your question, [edit] to clarify.
